# Using log4j instead of System.out.println()

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using system.out.println at a few places in my Java code. But the requirement is to remove those Sys outs and replace them with logger (log4j).

So, how can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, we hope you'll be happy here. Please read [ask] and then come back here to add the code that you've used to try to solve the problem and show us where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two stable version of log4j. Both versions are well documented. Please start solving your problem by reading the documentation.

- log4j 1.2 (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
- log4j 2 (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html)

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark this answer as your favourite answer. Thanks!